# OData query fails when combining all and any

Tags: odata

I'm using the OData Api v3 from Microsoft and trying to get the following query succeed:

```
Posts?$filter=(ReferredFrom/any(it: (it/ReferenceType/Description/Name eq 'Part')) and RefersTo/all(it: (it/ReferenceType/Description/Name ne 'Child')))
```

So it basically consists of two `all`/`any` query filers linked with `and`:

```
ReferredFrom/any(it: (it/ReferenceType/Description/Name eq 'Part'))
RefersTo/all(it: (it/ReferenceType/Description/Name ne 'Child')))
```

While both of the query parts work greatly on their own, I get an error when I combine them as shown above. Unfortunately, I get an `ArgumentNullException`. Does anyone of you know where's the problem? A similar query worked with an OData demo service.

Greetings, bloxx

This is the exact response:

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"Fehler"
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.\r\nParametername: parameter","type":"System.ArgumentNullException","stacktrace":"   bei System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- Ende der Stapel\u00fcberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgel\u00f6st wurde ---\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Ende der Stapel\u00fcberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgel\u00f6st wurde ---\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__21`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- Ende der Stapel\u00fcberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgel\u00f6st wurde ---\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure, but try this: Posts?$filter=ReferredFrom/any(from: from/ReferenceType/Description/Name eq 'Part') and RefersTo/all(to: to/ReferenceType/Description/Name ne 'Child')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Posts?$filter=ReferredFrom/any(from: from/ReferenceType/Description/Name eq 'Part') and RefersTo/all(to: to/ReferenceType/Description/Name ne 'Child')
```

http://www.odata.org/2012/05/odata-v3-demo-services/

and as a suggestion, never do same variable, but better categorize each:

instead of it, it  - do **from** , **to**.  in your case. It's even easier to read